# how do I rewrite jquery into no conflict mode?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on wordpress template. On xhtml files I had no problems with jquery, but now under wordpress no-conflict mode, my codes give errors.

How do I rewrite this into no-conflict?

```
//Fade in and out animation on hove buttons - meteo, and slide pagination balls
$(window).load(function() {
    $("ul.slidebtns li a").hover(function() {
        divW = ($(this).next("div").width() / 2) - ($(this).outerWidth() / 2);
        $(this).next("div").css({marginLeft: -divW }).animate({ opacity: "show" }, "fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this).next("div").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");
    });

    $("#tempicon img").hover(function() {
            var $img = $(this);
            var $labelDiv = $img.next("div");

            var halfOfLabelDivsWidth = $labelDiv.width() / 2;
            var imgMiddle = $img.position().left + ($img.width() / 2);

            $labelDiv
                .css({
                    left: imgMiddle - halfOfLabelDivsWidth
                })
                .animate({ opacity: "show" }, "fast");
        }, function() {
            $(this).next("div").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

Do I've to change ALL $ signs into jQuery? I tried to rewrite only parts like:

```
$(window).load(function() {
jQuery(window).load(function() {
```

and

```
$("ul.slidebtns li a").hover(function() {
jQuery("ul.slidebtns li a").hover(function() {
```

but it still errors out on $(this) for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code in an aliasing closure:

```
(function ($) {
    ...all your code here...
}(jQuery));
```

This will allow you to use `$` within the closure as a reference to the `jQuery` factory function.

If you're not willing to wrap everything in a closure (you'd have to watch out for `var` statements for example, as they might need to belong to a different context), you'd need to change *every* usage of `$` to `jQuery`.

Additionally, you're using `$(window).load`, which is usually unnecessary (unless you actually need images to have loaded). Instead you should be listening to the `document.ready` event. The long form is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    ...code...
});
```

But it's typically used in the aliasing shorthand form of:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
   ...code...
});
```

Comment: or like this:
$(document).ready(function(ev){
//code here
});